# How can I put scroll in my iphone view?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

in my viewDidLoad, there is too much data, 
so what should I do so that I can use all of them,
some sort of scroll, but how to code it ?

```
Picture (you cannot go to the next step if you do not input a picture. Existing or snap a new one)
Name
Age
Gender
Profession
Hobby
Things I like
Things I dislike
Business Address/Home Address (you choose one first and then you can type in the field)
Email Address
Other (this field does not have to match to others for a connection to be made)
Phone number (Automatically it will show the persons phone number)
```

There are fields, and I can make them, but there is not more space for me :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a UIScrollView. But you already know that I guess. Read this up [Learning the basics of UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595389/learning-the-basics-of-uiscrollview)

Alternatively, you may also explore UITableView if your data represents a logical group or set which can be presented as cells/rows on a TableView.

Comment: Data is not representing a logical group, but I tried UIScrollView, but can't see progress,

Comment: Did you read the post I'm pointing you to? It covers it very well. What is the issue you are having? Are you having a design issue in your app?

Comment: can I have scroll when my data is not so large?

Comment: You can have a scrollView anywhere. But common sense tells you that scroll should be used only when the data you are presenting cannot be possibly presented in the given screen real estate. Choose accordingly.

Comment: well dear it is working, but still it is starting from second page, horizentally, i don't know why effecting so ..... :-(