# How can I use UIScrollView?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, iphone

How can I use `UIScrollView`? please give me a simple example with one scrolling image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will get you an insight of the `UIScrollView` control:

[Learning the basics of UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595389/learning-the-basics-of-uiscrollview)

---

**Referenced from** [UIScrollView Tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820557/are-there-any-good-uiscrollview-tutorials-on-the-net/820748#820748)

Some good samples with the basic functionalities covered

- http://halmueller.wordpress.com/2008/10/08/a-very-simple-uiscrollview-demo/
- http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Scrolling/index.html
- http://www.vimeo.com/1642150
- http://jonathanwatmough.com/2008/12/implementing-tap-to-zoom-in-uiscrollview-on-an-iphone/
- http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html

Not to mention:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UIScrollView

Answer (score 5):

This can be one example. Basically we create a scrollview, set its frame, add content as a subview, and then set the content size. The image (iphone.png) below is bigger than the iphone screen so that we can scroll it.

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone.png"]];

[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageView.image.size.width, imageView.image.size.height);
[window addSubview:scrollView];
[scrollView release];
```

Comment: what is this line done ? in my code it is generate the error for window word.       [window addSubview:scrollView];

Comment: I test by putting this code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions above the [self.window makeKeyAndVisible], and it work fine. Actually window is the top window that is the parent of all view. I think you can put your parent view instead of window.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to answer. What this line done is adding a scrollview to its parent view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to add UIScrollView on yourView :-

```
[self.ScrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))];
```

Step:1 
  Create a UiScrollView,

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *MyScrollView;
@end
```

Step2:
  In your ViewController.m,

```
[self.MyScrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **UIImageView** in to **UIScrollView**.

then,

Use

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, imageView.image.size.width, imageView.image.size.height);
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageView.image.size.width, imageView.image.size.height);
```