# What is the best way to make this Customlayout – IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I need to make a [Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBWUy.png) like this, I think the best way to do this is with UICollectionViewFlowLayout, but I have not much experience with this component, most of my apps do using the Storyboard, I have seen several examples suggested in this ad but the problem is that most sizes assigned items randomly or automatically adjust the text, the need of fixed size within each item can go any content, image, text, video.

The numbers of the item are illustrative only, it can be any order

I hope someone can help me, sorry my English is not my native language

Comment: Maybe you can use UIScrollView and add every element manually.

Comment: You should use UIScrollView.

This topic may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883064/how-can-i-use-uiscrollview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the logic for that layout is probably too complex for `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. In that case, you'll have to create a new layout that extends from `UICollectionViewLayout` and specify the layout of items using that class by overwriting the `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` method. There's a good tutorial [from objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/collection-view-layouts.html).