# Designing inside a scrollview in xcode 4.2 with storyboards

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, storyboard

I have a vertically scrolling uiscrollview - imagine an 'about this app' page of a tab bar app which goes on a bit and requires a scrollview. It only contains a few images, a video and some text (only the video has been coded in - the rest have been placed in the GUI). In storyboard (Interface Builder?) Xcode 4.2, everything is set up as it should be and works fine, but the view is only as large as what you see on the screen, is it not possible to manually arrange in storyboard the items that are initially offscreen - that you need to scroll up to? The only way I've found so far is to design them on the visible view then navigate them down with the arrow keys..

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I feel your pain. The only way I found is to manually pan the scroll view in the size inspector to reveal the portion of the view that you wish to visually edit.

Use a UIView to contain elements so they are positioned relatively to this view. Add the view as a subview to the scrollview at 0,0.

1. pan: use the Y coordinate say to -200, then edit the contents.
2. to place more contents in the hidden part, pan again to reveal new real-estate
3. when finished, restore the values of the ScrollView's height and X,Y position.

Make sure the scroll view frame rectangle is smaller than the contained view.

Comment: Good solution to a problem that shouldn't exist!

Answer (score 51):

In the storyboard select the viewController, then in Attributes inspector change 'size' to 'freeform'. Then change the 'height' of the view/scroll view to as big as you need. The default settings of struts and springs should take care of resizing the view back correctly when the app is run, but you should double check.

Comment: This seems to work fine until I try to resize either the view or the scrollview in storyboard, at which point the content all warps in relation to the change in the view size...

Comment: To John, Actually this is not a problem. If you go to the "size inspector" for that scroll view and modify the "auto sizing". Clear both the horizontal and vertical arrows inside the rectangle. (I also clear the "right" and "bottom" arrows so my scroll view can tie to the top-left corner). Then the size of the scroll view should not be affected by the size of the parent view.

Comment: There is no such as size or freeform.

Comment: Oh there is. So make the UIScrollView as big as possible first and then count on Struts

Comment: great suggestion. note that the scrollview must be the root/main view in order for this to work.

Comment: I was a little confused with these instructions. After changing the ViewController to free form I just swapped over to the Size inspector with the ViewController still selected, then changed the height.

Answer (score 25):

New: 3/26/2013

I stumbled upon what I think is even simpler way of dealing with UIScrollView directly in storyboard.

1. No code needed, just storyboard settings. This maybe new in iOS6.1 / Xcode 4.6
2. No need to disable constraints (i.e. uncheck "Use autolayout" in File Inspector for storyboard file)
3. No need to add UIScrollView* scrollView; in .h
4. No need to add self.scrollView.contentSize = ... in overrides of viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad

Here is what I did (important parts highlighted with **): (see [code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wfvlmgsl9op5q5s/UIScrollView.zip))

1. Create a new project with storyboard enabled
2. Drop in a UIScrollView, set class in identity inspector for view controller
3. In attributes Inspector, change Size under simulated metrics to Freeform**
4. Select scroll View; In attributes inspector, turn on "scroll enabled" and "background" to "White" (you'll figure out why - if you don't)
5. Under Size Inspector (with scroll view selected) change the height to 900 for example**
6. Add buttons, one on top and one at the bottom
7. Add a default handler for buttonTouchUpInside for both buttons and simply Log sender.

See [Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wfvlmgsl9op5q5s/UIScrollView.zip) Select the View Controller and scroll view and check inspectors.

Comment: There is alot of literature on this subject, but you're the first I've come across that actually answers the damn question. FREEFORM is what fixes it. I spent a damn long time trying to figure this out, thank you for sharing!

Comment: freeform of the view controller?

Answer (score 12):

Just change the 'Simulated Size' of the view controller to freeform and set a height that is larger than the usual size, you will be able to see all the outlets you need to edit.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.. much more elegant solution

Answer (score 4):

On iOS 6.0 you can drag a Container View inside your Scroll View. This will automatically create a new View for your content, outside of the current scene. You can then resize this view as big as needed to fit your content.

I believe you would still have to set the ScrollView content height at runtime, but at least you can design you content view at once without having to scroll up and down on IB.

Comment: I think you should set the height of the Container View, instead of the ScrollView's content height. What I would like to know is how to set the Container Views height to the height of the embedded view using layout constraints. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2):

Just uncheck the "Autoresize subviews" from any view that you're trying to resize and it should keep all your objects from resizing with it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for a while now, and every single thing I've tried has failed.

Specifically, What I am trying to achieve is a freeform sized modal dialog with a scrollable view containing a container for another view. I have had a lot of varied results, including occasionally having it working correctly. Most often I get it looking exactly correct, but with no scrolling.

In finally downloaded Dickey Singh's code, which worked perfectly but had nothing special. (Excellent clean solution BTW). So, I added a container view to it, exactly as I had in my code, and it broke!

After some experimenting, I worked out what is going on. Just bear with me.

1) Using Auto Layout, the size of the scroll view seems to dictate what the scrolling bounds will be. Setting "contentSize" in "USer Defined Runtime Attributes" seems to have no effect on this, and neither does setting "contentSize" or "bounds" in "viewWillDisplay" or "viewDidLoad". Thus if the initial size of the scroll view is 800x800, that will be all the space that can be displayed. For this reason, when I want a scrollable region, I create a container view and then put the scrolling view inside the content.

2) Without Auto Layout, setting "contentSize" in "User Defined Runtime Attributes" works, as does by setting it programmatically in "viewDidLoad". I prefer to use "User Defined Runtime Attributes" because it keeps the size with the layout. This solution allows you to use scrolling view with more flexibility, since it can be any size at design time.

3) Regardless of Auto Layout, if any view within the scrolling region exactly matches EITHER the horizontal or vertical frame bounds, then the scroll view ceases to function as a scroll view. This applies to my own code and to Dickey Singh's code in every possible configuration that I have tried.

I have no idea what is causing (3), but it is clearly a bug.

I hope this helps everybody out there who is struggling to use scroll view. I imagine that some people are using them without any problem, and some (like me) have had noting but problems with them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to design a ScrollView with a content larger than the screen entirely in Storyboard (well, except for 1 single line of code :-) :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19476991/1869369

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently developing an app for iOS 7, and I did exactly as @Dickey Singh's answer, but it doesn't work in the beginning. 
After checking the storyboard, I found that we also need to add Auto Layout Constraints for the view controller who holds the scrollView. 
It seems that such auto layout constraints would be added automatically before Xcode 5, but now we need to do it ourselves.
The way to add constraints: First select the view controller in the storyboard; Enter 'Editor' in the top menu; Select the 'Resolve Auto Layout Issues'; Select the 'Add Missing Constraints In Container'. Done :-)