# UIScrollView stopped scrolling on iOS7

Tags: uiscrollview, ios7

This worked perfectly before. Here is my view hierarchy.

[image]

I've set contentSize property, but on iOS7 scrollview is not scrolling at all

[image]

Comment: did you try double checking that autolayout is off?

Comment: but the autolayout is on...

Comment: Yeah, i had turned that off and it worked.

Comment: BUt I don't want to turn that off. I'd have to keep view in separate nib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the better way is to use pure autolayout approach which contains:

- scrollview has all side constraints bound to superview
- container view (inside scrollview) has all side constraints bound to superview (which is scrollview)
- additionally container view has height and width constraints set to the dimensions of scrollview

And that's it, works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I think you had set some scroll frame in the .m class ,and try to give the scroll content size in .m class.If you had set the frame in .m it may be get conflict.

Answer (score 0):

After many project, I finally found the solution (or maybe is there a bug correction from Apple).

What you just have to do is to add a constraint to the "bottom Space to Superview" (ex. to 20). Like this, iOS know what is the content height.

Good example : [UIScrollView doesn't scroll after upgrading to iOS7 / xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751742/uiscrollview-doesnt-scroll-after-upgrading-to-ios7-xcode-5?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Programatically,

Léni.