# UIScrollView with AutoLayout works perfectly in iOS 6 but not in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, autolayout

### The context

I am building a `UIViewController` using Storyboards and AutoLayout.

My ViewController has the following structure:

[image: UIViewController structure]

### What I did

I have set all the layout constraints for all views inside the `UIScrollView` properly. So, I have set all the height and vertical distance constraints for all views. I have set all IBOutlets correctly also.

### The Problem

When I run it on iOS 6, it works **like a charm**. But, when running on iOS 7, it doesn't. When I try to scroll the view, I can see the vertical scroll indicator moving down (in a weird way, cause it is getting smaller when I am scrolling down).

Any thoughts about what is happening?

Comment: Have you read about iOS 7 changes from iOS 6 ?

Comment: Yes. I've read. My issue is probably the same reported here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751742/uiscrollview-doesnt-scroll-after-upgrading-to-ios7-xcode-5). But I don't want to remove the autolayout. I saw that it is possible to let the system automatically calculates the scrollview content size based on its constraints. But I don't know why it is happening here. Do you have some link/info/tips to provide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple posted [TN2154](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) in May 2013, titled "UIScrollView And Autolayout". It probably has the info you need to solve this. It includes both a "Mixed Approach" (i.e. by turning off autolayout constraints for part of the view hierarchy) and a "Pure Auto Layout Approach" which requires declaring additional constraints in code for the scrollview's subviews so they don't depend on the scrollview's size for layout. It's a good read.