# UIScrollview scroll not working

Tags: uiscrollview, autolayout, constraints, ios8, xcode6

UIScrollview scroll is not working when i tested application in device (iPhone 5), But scroll is working properly in iPhone 5/5s/6/6 Plus simulator. I am developing application using `Xcode 6` and `UIStoryboard` with `AutoLayout`.

I set the top, bottom, left and right constraints of UIScrollview with relative to Superview. And i also set the constraints of every UIControl which is in the UIScrollview.

Has any one have solution regarding this issue?

Please see below screenshot for reference.

[image]

Comment: Try this one ,it should help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751742/uiscrollview-doesnt-scroll-after-upgrading-to-ios7-xcode-5

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to have the scroll view contain a single view, which then contains all of your scrollable content. That single view should be anchored to all 4 sides of the scroll view, and if it's only meant to scroll vertically (which is what your screenshot makes it look like), then set the content view to be the same width as the *parent* of the scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure an UIScrollView scroll, you have to check

1. **Size**

Your content View is bigger than your Scroll View. If you want it to be scrolled vertically, make sure its higher; horizontally, wider.

2. **Constraints**

Make sure your Scroll View is pinned to its super view, Top, Bottom, Leading, Trailing.

Make sure your **Content view** of Scroll View **DOES NOT have CenterY constraint set to Scroll View**, cause that'd make content view stuck with Scroll View and it'd never be able to scroll. (That happens to me the last time I was stuck)

3. **Interface Builder settings**

Make sure the check in Interface Builder under Scroll View is checked: 
Scrolling section, **Scrolling Enabled**.