# iOS7 Visible ScrollView Using Storyboards

Tags: uiscrollview, ios7, storyboard, xcode5

I'm finding it incredibly frustrating to get a simple scrollview working in iOS 7 with Xcode 5.

I've read the existing threads and followed them over and over and over again. Ive googled the topic for tuts (all of which did it a different way which makes me think there is no simple solution.) none of them have worked so far.

Can anyone explain how to do this in simple steps and possibly expand on what role Auto Layout plays in all of this (I know very little about autolayout, but it seems to be linked to this problem in some way).

Comment: What have you done so far? What is the problem? Please explain more.

Comment: this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905568/how-do-i-use-scrollview-in-storyboard

and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809984/designing-inside-a-scrollview-in-xcode-4-2-with-storyboards

and every other result on google in the first 2 pages when u google any combination of "scrollview storyboards tutorial ios7"