# How to show a PDF Page by Page using the Three20 Project - iPhone

Tags: iphone, pdf, iphone-sdk-3.0, three20, pdf-reader

I have a large local PDF.
How can I use three20 Project for showing the PDF page by page with zooming, swiping functionalities?

Is there any other free library available to achieve this functionality?

I tried to use the Apple WWDC 2010 code but facing some problems (I am showing PDF Pages instead of images). The question related to it is here,
[In photoscroller app (iPhone WWDC-104 Photos App) uiscrollview images shift to right when called using presentModalviewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854508/in-photoscroller-app-iphone-wwdc-104-photos-app-uiscrollview-images-shift-to-ri)

Kindly help me.

Comment: I think your previous approach was a better one. The most likely answer to your UIScrollView problem would seem to be that one of the sizes / offsets has ended up incorrect somehow. Try posting more of your code in the original question, or providing a copy of the whole project people can download to see.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that Three20 can achieve this? Three20 is not a magical library that can solve all of the problems in iPhone OS. Try using the normal approach, one of them is available in [this blog post](http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2010/06/rendering-pdf-is-easier-than-you-thought/).