# Horizontal paged UIScrollView with a gap between each view -- views aren't centered

Tags: objective-c, gaps-in-visuals

Apple's WWDC 2010 Tutorial Video "Designing Apps with Scroll Views" works well with iOS 4, but with iOS 5 the pages are not centered:

[image]

It seems that

```
pagingScrollViewFrame.origin.x -= PADDING;
```

doesn't work in iOS 5.

My code is the following:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

#define PADDING  10

- (void)loadView 
{    

    // Step 1: make the outer paging scroll view
    CGRect pagingScrollViewFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    pagingScrollViewFrame.origin.x -= PADDING;
    pagingScrollViewFrame.size.width += (2 * PADDING);

    pagingScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:pagingScrollViewFrame];
    pagingScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    pagingScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    pagingScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    pagingScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    pagingScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagingScrollView.bounds.size.width * 6, pagingScrollView.bounds.size.height);
    pagingScrollView.delegate = self;
    self.view = pagingScrollView;

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        CGRect bounds = pagingScrollView.bounds;
        CGRect pageFrame = bounds;
        pageFrame.size.width -= (2 * PADDING);
        pageFrame.origin.x = (bounds.size.width * i) + PADDING;
        view.frame = pageFrame;
        [pagingScrollView addSubview:view];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES   
                                    withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

```
pageFrame.origin.x = (bounds.size.width * i) + PADDING;
```

change this part to

```
pageFrame.origin.x = (bounds.size.width + PADDING) * i;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Unfortunately, this works only for the first of six views.
Basically, I only need to know how to set a negative origin point (lets say x = -10, y = 0) using the iOS 5 SDK to archive my goal. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: because you made scrollview of 6 page width (pagingScrollView.bounds.size.width * 6)

Comment: I don't understand. The content size of the scrollview must be as long as the total size of all pages inside. The content size defines the scroll range. so what's wrong with that?

Comment: When I use a UIScrollView with six views and without the gap between each view, it works fine. But I want to have these gap between the views. Basically I want the same as the iPhone photos app in fullscreen mode. The gap between the images occurs only while scrolling/switch from one image to the next. Unfortunately, I don't know how to archive that.

Comment: Used successfully [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849383/photos-app-like-gap-between-pages-in-uiscrollview-with-pagingenabled) approach.